# htaccess remove directories from url

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

My main problem is that i got a lot of directories that i want to hide from the customer visiting my website.

my base url: http://example.com/qf/development/templates/webApp/

What i want to hide for the visiting customer is these directories "/qf/development/templates/"

I have tried with the following in my .htaccess file in the directory http://example.com/.htaccess in the web root

This is whats inside my .htaccess file but not working..

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^qf$ qf/development/templates/webApp/index.php

Comment: you don't want to hide the folders in webApp ?

Comment: I actually want to hide them all... I'm currently working on your solution...

Comment: My solution will actually hide them all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this rule

```
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteBase / 
 RewriteRule ^qf/?$ qf/development/templates/webApp/index.php [L,NC]
```

This will redirect www.example.com/qf **to**  www.example.com/qf/development/templets/webApp/index.php

**Or**

Add the following line to your .htaccess file

```
   IndexIgnore *dir
```

This tells the Apache web server to list all files except those that is in the IndexIgnore

**example 1** 
add the following line to your .htaccess file if you want to hide a directory named **foo**

```
 IndexIgnore *foo
```

**example 2** 
add the following line to your .htaccess file if you want to hide a file that ends with **.bar**

```
  IndexIgnore *.bar
```

If you want to disable all files and directories form listing ,Add this line to your .htaccess

```
  IndexIgnore *
```

The wildcard '*' means it will not display any files

Answer (score 0):

*My solution :*

in your current **.htaccess** :

```
RewriteEngine off
Options -Indexes
```

This will prevent the directories listing of all the hierarchy from your root.

In your document root, you create a **index.php** containing :

```
<?php header('Location: http://example.com/qf/development/templates/webApp/');
```

in `/qf/development/templates/webApp/`, you just create the **index.php** (disallowing directories listing will not disallow files access, **index.php** will still be requestable).

Comment: My problem isn't an index problem... I simply want to hide the directories (qf/development/templates/) in the URL so that it says http://example.com/webApp/index.php :)